# Trackpad driver

Tags: drivers

I have an hp pavilion that came with windows 7. It has a feature that when I slide two fingers across the track pad it scrolls the current page. This works well in Windows 7 but does not work in Ubuntu. In windows I can go to device manager and at least find out what drivers I'm missing. Is there something in Ubuntu that is analogous to this? Somewhere where I can see what hardware I have and what drivers I need to make it work?

Comment: Did you try the Mouse preferences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu comes prepared for plug'n-play many devices. So probably you don't need to install any drivers.

The feature you are looking for is "Two finger scroll" and it can be turned on in *Mouse & Touchpad* section of **System Settings**. There are two ways you can get into *Mouse & Touchpad* section:

**1.** Open **System Settings** by clicking in its icon in the Launcher or by selecting it from System Menu or by searching for `System Settings` in the Dash, all illustrated bellow:

[image: System Settings from Launcher] [image: System Settings from System Menu] [image: System Settings from Dash]

And then select *Mouse & Touchpad* section:

[image: Mouse & Touchpad]

**2.** The other way to go directly to *Mouse & Touchpad* is by searching for `Mouse` or `Touchpad` in the Dash:

[image: Mouse & Touchpad search]

Once in *Mouse & Touchpad* section you can tweak your settings, to enable two finger scrolling you just need to check this option:

[image: Two finger scrolling]

Comment: Oh that was easy. Thanks a lot. The scrolling works even better then it does in Windows.