# Magic mouse back/forward in browser

Tags: magic-mouse

I have an Apple Magic Mouse, not the trackpad, and it supports vertical and horizontal scrolling, but it doesn't go back/forward in a browser, the way it does on a Mac.

Are there any settings to enable this behaviour?

Comment: I had the same question. The fine folks on Ask Ubuntu were able to help me out. http://askubuntu.com/questions/308713/trackpad-driver

Comment: Not exactly the same, but is a good bet.